# dismissViewControllerAnimated issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

The first screen of my app consists of the login screen. I am displaying the login screen from `AppDelegate`.
The login screen comes up and I am able to go to next screen in the simulator. But it doesn't work on device.

On device, the main screen comes up for a second and the login screen is displayed. I tried changing the order of `[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and  `[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];` but that doesn't work either.

I am running on a iOS 9.0 iPad (device). Everything seems fine on simulator though.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = nil;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self->_loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];    
    self.window.rootViewController = nil;
    self.window.rootViewController = self->_loginViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)loginUser {

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
       //load xib for iPad
       mainVC = [[MainVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainVC~ipad" bundle:nil];

    } else if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       //load xib for iPhone
       mainVC = [[MainVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainVC~iphone" bundle:nil];
    }

    self.navigationController = nil;
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
    //    [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //not working

        [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //not working
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.navigationController animated:YES completion:nil]; 

      //not working
      //  [self.window.rootViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
      //      [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
      //   }];

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you are setting up `LoginViewController` as the rootController of the window which is fine. In your login method you are trying to dismiss a controller when none is presented here(assuming you have not presented any other controller). You can remove that line and just present the navigation controller.

Comment: I removed this `[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and kept only this  `  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ { 
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.navigationController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
    }); ` . But still it's of no use.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I normally change my `rootViewController`. In your case, when your user has logged on replace:

```
[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //not working
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

with:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

And then on user logout do:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.loginViewController;
```